# DynamoDB getItem - expected item to be a S when its an N

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have one row in a table where the N value is 1 and not 0. This field is called active_duty_manager and I want to pull back the row where the value is 1 so I can get the user credentials.

When I query the table using the following code:

```
var params = {
               AttributesToGet: ['mobile'],
               TableName: 've-users',
               Key: { 'is_active_duty_manager': {N:1} },
               };
ddb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) { 
console.log(err);
  } else { // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
           console.log("Success, duty manager =",data.Item.user_id.N);
      }
  })
```

I get the following Error:

```
{ InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Key['is_active_duty_manager'].N to be a string  
at ParamValidator.fail (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
at ParamValidator.validateType (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:222:10)
at ParamValidator.validateString (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:154:32)
at ParamValidator.validateScalar (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:130:21)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:94:21)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
at ParamValidator.validateMap (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/Users/kevin/lambda/dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
  message: 'Expected params.Key[\'is_active_duty_manager\'].N to be a string',
  code: 'InvalidParameterType',
  time: 2018-02-26T20:13:09.795Z }
```

[image]

[image]

If I export a row as a CSV I can see the column type are S or N and, for example, active_duty_manager, is definitely a Number. So the question is why the error expects params.Key value to be a string?

Many thanks
Kevin

Comment: Try changing it the value of `N` to be `"1"` (stringified 1). That's the right way of querying.

Comment: I think you have another problem though. `GetItem` needs a primary key and `is_active_duty_manager` is not a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at your table you have a primary key on user_id. This means you cannot write a query on this table which will give you the asked results, no matter what you write it won't work.

As I see it you basically have two options:

1. write a scan with a filter on is_active_duty_manager equals 0,
   this is however a fairly expensive one as it will always read all
   items.
2. Make a global secondary index on is_active_duty_manager and only
   write 1 to it and leave it blank otherwise. This way you will get a
   sparse index with just items which have this value set. You can then
   query this index and this will be very fast and cheap.

When your table will be very small option 1 might still work for you. Cost optimization is a little bit out of scope here, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried the secondary index but I think the attempts I must have not parseInt(num).toString or something.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to define the key like 
`Key: { 'is_active_duty_manager': {'N':'1'} },`

You may need to restructure your entire params with quotes.

```js
var params = {
  "AttributesToGet": ["mobile"],
  "TableName": "ve-users",
  "Key": { "is_active_duty_manager": {"N":"1"} },
};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html

Here is the Request Syntax from the DynamoDB API Reference:

```js
{
   "AttributesToGet": [ "string" ],
   "ConsistentRead": boolean,
   "ExpressionAttributeNames": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   },
   "Key": { 
      "string" : { 
         "B": blob,
         "BOOL": boolean,
         "BS": [ blob ],
         "L": [ 
            "AttributeValue"
         ],
         "M": { 
            "string" : "AttributeValue"
         },
         "N": "string",
         "NS": [ "string" ],
         "NULL": boolean,
         "S": "string",
         "SS": [ "string" ]
      }
   },
   "ProjectionExpression": "string",
   "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "string",
   "TableName": "string"
}
```